# ASP.NET Core pages being rendered as plain HTML

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I have created a new project from scratch downloading the latest stable build for ASP.NET 7. but  vs 2022 throws an exception "The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:\r\n/Views/Home/Index.cshtml\r\n/Views/" and then the MVC application does not load, also tried adding this extension for razor views? AddRazorRuntimeCompilation but now the application is rendering HTML content in black and white before adding swagger it was working as expected, i wanted to have swagger alongside an MVC project to check the endpoints but I dont know if this somehow affected the project I have added the following packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="7.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="6.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="6.5.0" />
```

```
using ACO.Data;
using ACO.Data.Entity;
using ACO.Extensions;
using ACO.Middleware;
using ACO.Services.Contracts;
using ACO.Services.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Reflection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGenService();

builder.Services.Configure<ProductoStoreDatabaseSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDbSettings:ProductoStoreDabaseSettings"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IProductoStoreDatabaseSettings>(sp=> sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ProductoStoreDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(s => new MongoClient(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MongoDbSettings:ConnectionString")));

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(ProductoService));
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

var app = builder.Build();



// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    //app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ProductoService v1"));
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    //{
    //    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ProductoService v1");
    //});
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseMiddleware<GlobalResquestHandlerMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Could you share the network information in Browser Developer Tools ? I want to check if it has some errors here.

Comment: @JasonPan turns out i had to change in my middleware the content type response to html text to be able to render at the time I was returning only json on the type